# Nested UpdatePanel Behavior

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am using a Wizard control in an UpdatePanel.  Some of the Wizard Steps have UpdatePanels nested inside.  Both the outer and inner UpdatePanels have their own Trigger collection.  All of the events fire as intended.

However, the triggers for the outer UpdatePanel do not set off the UpdateProgress control.  The inner ones all do.  I'm stumped as to why I can't get the outer Triggers to show the ProgressTemplate.  It's for some ImageButtons that navigate the Wizard Steps.

Outlined, the nesting is as follows:

```
UpdatePanel
   Triggers
   ContentTemplate
      UpdateProgress
      Wizard
         Step #n
         UpdatePanel
            Triggers
            ContentTemplate
                   .
                   .
            /ContentTemplate
         /UpdatePanel
         /Step
                .
                .
      /Wizard
   /ContentTemplate
/UpdatePanel
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you associating the UpdateProgress with your nested UpdatePanel?

Can you provide your full tags for the UpdatePanels and UpdateProgress?  It would help to see if there is something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Your [UpdateProgress](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/overview/UpdateProgressOverview.aspx) needs to be outside your outermost UpdatePanel and do not associate it with any specific UpdatePanel.

> You associate an UpdateProgress
>   control with an UpdatePanel control by
>   setting the AssociatedUpdatePanelID
>   property of the UpdateProgress
>   control. When a postback event
>   originates from an UpdatePanel
>   control, any associated UpdateProgress
>   controls are displayed. If you do not
>   associate the UpdateProgress control
>   with a specific UpdatePanel control,
>   the UpdateProgress control displays
>   progress for any asynchronous
>   postback.
>
> If the ChildrenAsTriggers property of
>   a UpdatePanel control is set to false
>   and an asynchronous postback
>   originates from inside that
>   UpdatePanel control, any associated
>   UpdateProgress controls will be
>   displayed.